# How to change Android Loading icon position?

Tags: android, android-layout

First image:
[image]

Second image:
[image]

First XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="99.81"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4.47"
        android:background="@drawable/search_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_search_bar" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#dddddd" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/player_frag_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Second XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_view_upcoming"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_upcoming"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_view_completed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/label_completed" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#dddddd" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Please anyone who can help me change my first loading to make it middle like second loading?

Comment: Magic...!! How you are able to show loading bar? It's not there in XML.

Comment: I am using Android Loader, I think isn't coding issues, so I do not post it

Comment: Post some java code and give more description.

Answer (score 2):

try using the following attribute of activity in Manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or "adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 2):

I am already solved it.

i changed layout height on second xml to:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_view_upcoming"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_upcoming"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_view_completed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/label_completed" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#dddddd" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: If you didn't add that **soft keyboard** before, you may get this answer by some one long back. ;-)